# Subform opening with previous filter

Tags: ms-access, vba

I've created a main form with a subform on it. The subform is filtered using a couple of combo boxes and command buttons on the main form.

For some strange reason when the form is closed and reopened, the subform is already showing as if it is filtered.

The method I'm using to filter the subform is to build an sql string that will be used as the subform's recordsource when a command button is pressed to apply the filter.

Here's the function that builds that sql string:

```vb
Public Function strSfaPaymentRecordSource() As String

    strSfaPaymentRecordSource = "SELECT " _
                              & "[tblSfaRemittances].ID, [tblSfaRemittances].[SfaBudget], " _
                              & "[tblSfaRemittances].[PfrFundingLine], [tblSfaRemittances].[ContractNo], " _
                              & "[tblSfaRemittances].[LedgerDesc], [tblSfaRemittances].[TransDesc], " _
                              & "[tblSfaRemittances].[Period], [tblSfaRemittances].[Amount], [tblSfaRemittances].[Memo] " _
                              & "FROM tblSfaRemittances"

    If Me.cboFundingLine > "" Or Me.cboReturnPeriod > "" Then       
        strSfaPaymentRecordSource = strSfaPaymentRecordSource & " WHERE"        
    End If

    If Me.cboFundingLine > "" Then      
        strSfaPaymentRecordSource = strSfaPaymentRecordSource & " PfrFundingLine = '" & Me.cboFundingLine & "' And"         
    End If

    If Me.cboReturnPeriod > "" Then     
        strSfaPaymentRecordSource = strSfaPaymentRecordSource & " Period = '" & Me.cboReturnPeriod & "'"            
    End If

    If Right(strSfaPaymentRecordSource, 4) = " And" Then
        strSfaPaymentRecordSource = Left(strSfaPaymentRecordSource, Len(strSfaPaymentRecordSource) - 4)
    End If

End Function
```

And then the command button assigns the subform recordsource to the above string function:

```vb
Private Sub CmdApplyFilter_Click()

    Me.frmSfaRemittances_sub.Form.RecordSource = strSfaPaymentRecordSource

End Sub
```

Now though, whenever I open the form, the subform is already filtered the same way (even if I filter it another way, close the form and come back to it).

I've checked the subform's recordsource and there is no `WHERE` clause saved there. I've also ran `Debug.Print` on the subform recordsource when the form and subform opens and still there is no `WHERE` clause being applied.

There's no code running on the any of the form or subform.form events, so I'm kind of at a loss as to why it's behaving this way. Any pointers would be appreciated :)

Comment: If you open the subform independently in Design View, then check the Filter property on the Data tab of its property sheet --- is that Filter property blank?

Comment: If it isn't the filter, is there a link between main form and subform? If `LinkMasterFields` and `LinkChildFields` of the subform control aren't empty, it would filter the subform according to the first record of the main form.

Comment: Unrelated: see the second half of http://stackoverflow.com/a/33630318/3820271 to simplify your WHERE clause construction.

Comment: @HansUp the Filter property is blank, although the problem seems to have stopped anyway. I went in to the query builder for the subform's recordsource, didn't change anything but saved it and then it started to work as expected. Andre451 the link master/child fields are blank as my form isn't bound to a recordsource; thank you for that WHERE clause tip.. saved me some code!

Comment: Almost certainly you will have made a change to the subform having switched from form view to design view and saved it, thereby saving the filter or query. Done this a lot myself.