# MS Access VBA concatenate variables dynamically in SQL

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I have a form with 7 checkboxes, each checkbox is a status: Open, Closed, Rejected, Postponed, Working, Duplicated and Testing

The value of checkbox can be True or False.

Now I would like to have the value of the checkbox to be concatenated in a SQL statement in VBA:

```
Dim Status As String
If (Open.value = True) Then Status = " status = 'Open'" End If
If (Postponed.value = True) Then Status = " or status = 'Postponed'" End If
If (Closed.value = True) Then Status = " or status = 'Closed'" End If
If (Rejected.value = True) Then Status = " or status = 'Rejected'" End If
If (Working.value = True) Then Status = " or status = 'Working'" End If
If (Duplicated.value = True) Then Status = " or status = 'Duplicated'" End If
If (Testing.value = True) Then Status = " or status = 'Testing'" End If
sqlstatement = "select * from cr where " & status
```

The issue with above code is that it is kinda hard coded. Meaning that if open.value is not true, then the whole statement is wrong. So how to make it dynamic to assemble only the criterias in where (any checkbox can be selected or dis-selected)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from the second part of this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33630318/3820271

```
Status = ""
If (Open.value = True) Then Status = Status & " OR status = 'Open'" 
If (Postponed.value = True) Then Status = Status & " OR status = 'Postponed'"
If (Closed.value = True) Then Status = Status & " OR status = 'Closed'"
' ...
sqlstatement = "select * from cr where 1=0 " & status
```

How does it work?

Every criterium is added with `OR`. The statement has a default WHERE clause that is False. If no checkbox if checked, no records are returned (I assume that is what you want).

Note: If you have `If ... Then ...` in a single line, you must not use `End If`. Your code wouldn't compile.

Comment: Thanks, I accepted your answer because it is a simpler solution.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have matched names between the checkboxes and the fields, and presuming there are no other checkboxes:

```
Dim status As String
Dim ctl As Control
status = ""
For Each ctl In Me.Controls
    If ctl.ControlType = acCheckBox Then
        status = status & " or status = '" & ctl.Name & "'"
    End If
Next
if not status = "" then
    sqlstatement = "select * from cr where " & Mid(status, 5)
End if
```

Comment: Thanks, I have more checkboxes on the same page, so I wonder if this would work in the scenarios.

Comment: If you have other checkboxes that you don't want to include then your could try adding a tag to the ones you want and add a check for that tag with the check for the controltype.